# How to get the manifest of an image before building the image

Tags: manifest, yocto, bitbake

In yocto, I would like to review what will be built (packages and versions) in an image without actually building it (because it takes too much time). How could I achieve this?

`bitbake -g core-image-minimal` gives some information, but I would like something closer to the image's manifest.

`bitbake -e core-image-minimal` does not give the list of all packages.

Answer (score -1):

`bitbake -g core-image-minimal` will write a file `pn-buildlist` which is a list of all recipes that are in the dependency tree.

Comment: pn-buildlist contains also `-native` packages, that will not be embedded. And it does not indicate versions.

Comment: If you want to know exactly what goes into an image, then you need to build the image.  For example setting IMAGE_FEATURES to dev-pkgs will dynamically pull in packages at rootfs time based on globs, which are unknowable without building the image.